# Sensing button pressed python

Tags: python, tkinter

So I wrote this code for a little project we're doing

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

win = Tkinter.Tk()

def add_num(number):
    number=number+5

win.geometry("500x300")
win.wm_title("Numbers")
butt=Tkinter.Button(win, text ="HOLD MEH!!!", command = add_num(5))
butt.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Now this program only ads numbers when I'm clicking it. What would be the **simplest** way here, so that it would be calling the function over and over again, if it was pressed? I really want it to be **simple** as it can.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the demonstration down below. The `MyButton` class repeats the `command` as quickly as possible while the button is held down. You can alter the `start` method to schedule the `command` less frequently if needed. Just call the `after` method and remember to fill in the `ms` parameter with an appropriate wait time.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *

class Demo(Frame):

    QVGA = 320, 240

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        NoDefaultRoot()
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Demo')
        root.minsize(*cls.QVGA)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame = cls(root)
        frame.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.var = IntVar(self)
        self.label = Label(self, textvariable=self.var)
        self.label.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        self.button = MyButton(self, text='Hold Me', command=self.add)
        self.button.grid(sticky=EW)

    def add(self):
        self.var.set(self.var.get() + 1)

class MyButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        self.command = kw.pop('command')
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.start)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.stop)

    def start(self, event):
        self.handle = self.after_idle(self.start, event)
        self.command()

    def stop(self, event):
        self.after_cancel(self.handle)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Demo.main()
```

Comment: OP is not using python3, which might cause some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`command=` expect function name without `()` (and arguments)

Using

```
command = add_num(5)
```

you run `add_num(5)` and result of this function is assigned to `command=`

Your function have no `return` so it return `None` as default.

Finnaly you code means almost this:

```
add_num(5) # run function once
Button( commnad=None ) # no function assigned to `command=`
```

You can assing function with arguments in two ways:

1 - with another function:

```
def add_five():
   add_num(5)

Button( commnad=add_five )
```

2 - with `lambda`

```
Button( commnad= lambda : add_num(5) )
Button( commnad=lambda:add_num(5) ) # less spaces in code
```

---

BTW: you should keep result in differnt variable to add again and again

```
result = 0

def add_num(number):
    global result 

    result = result + number

    print "new result:", result
```